# An exercise about basis for orthogonal subspace (solution check)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I believe what I did in this exercise is correct, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this kind of computation. I'm practicing for an exam that requires me to be really fast solving problems.

**Exercise**.Consider the following inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

\begin{equation}
\langle(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}),(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4})\rangle=2x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+x_{3}y_{3}+x_{4}y_{4}.
\end{equation}

Find a basis to the subspace $W^{\perp}$ orthogonal to the subspace $W=[(1,2,0,-1),(2,0,-1,1)]$.

**My solution.** Let $w=(w_{1},w_{2},w_{3},w_{4})\in W^{\perp}$. Then

\begin{equation}
\langle (w_{1},w_{2},w_{3},w_{4}),(1,2,0,-1)\rangle =0,
\end{equation}
which gives me the equation $2w_{1}+2w_{2}-w_{4}=0$, and

\begin{equation}
\langle (w_{1},w_{2},w_{3},w_{4}),(2,0,-1,1)\rangle =0,
\end{equation}
which gives me the equation $4w_{1}-w_{3}+w_{4}=0$.

Treating $w_{3}$ and $w_{4}$ as free parameters, we have that any such $w$ is of the form

\begin{equation}
w=(\frac{w_{3}+w_{4}}{4},\frac{-w_{3}+3w_{4}}{4},w_{3},w_{4})=w_{3}(\frac{1}{4},\frac{-1}{4},1,0)+w_{4}(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},0,1).
\end{equation}
Thus, since the above vectors in the linear combination are linearly independent, they are a basis for $W^{\perp}$.

Is this correct? Is this the quickest way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct, and as efficient as you can get. The only way to solve this problem is to solve the system of 2 equations.